# Feign + Consul: Enable only discovery (client), not registration (service)

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign, spring-cloud-consul

Quoting the [docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-consul/1.2.1.RELEASE/):

> @EnableDiscoveryClient make the app into both a Consul "service" (i.e.
>   it registers itself) and a "client" (i.e. it can query Consul to
>   locate other services).

How can I configure a Spring Boot application that uses Feign as REST client and looks up service-instances in Consul but without registering the application itself at Consul?

I tried:

a. Various combinations of

```
spring.cloud.consul.enabled = true
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.enabled = true
```

b. Do not use the annotation at all, only

```
@EnableFeignClients
// @EnableDiscoveryClient
```

which produces an exception during the call:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'ribbonServerList' defined in
>   org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulRibbonClientConfiguration:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'ribbonServerList'
>   parameter 1; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulDiscoveryProperties'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

My `FeingClient` interface is annotated like this:

```
@FeignClient(value = "test-service")
```

where test-service is a successfully registered service in Consul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `@EnableDiscoveryClient(autoRegister=false)`.

Comment: Of course, that's it. Thank you, Spencer, once again. NB: This property was introduced in `Dalston` (1.2.x).